# Azure Table Controllers - Get records by to parameters

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I am working on an Azure Mobile Apps project. Where I have to define a Table Controller with that can accept two parameters and give a list of values. I have a DataObject for `ProductItem`, which is

```
public class ProductItem : EntityData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get a specific Product item, filter by its Price and Merchant. Already in the `ProductItemContoller`, I have scaffolded

```
// GET tables/ProductItem
public IQueryable<ProductItem> GetAllProductItems()
{
    return Query();
}

// GET tables/ProductItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
public SingleResult<ProductItem> GetProductItem(string id)
{
    return Lookup(id);
}
```

by looking at existing examples. But in examples, we have not called any of the given methods from Client. Rather, `IEnumerable<ProductItem> items = await productTable.ToEnumerableAsync();` was called.

My question is why can't we call `GetAllProductItems()` which was already defined in the controller to the client. If we can call, how to do it.

And also, I need to have a controller method, I need to have a `GetAllProductByMerchat(string merchantId)`. How can I make this possible.

Comment: Do you get a chance to address the solution for this case?  I am stuck exactly on this.   The MSDN documents are vague and doesn't tell how to consume the custom API's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Table controllers are called automatically by the client SDKs on your behalf, allowing you to work with LINQ queries on the client.  You can use something like:

```
var items = productTable.Where(p => p.Price < 100).ToListAsync();
```

This gets translated into an OData query across the wire, then translated back into a LINQ query on the server, where it then gets translated into SQL and executed on the SQL Azure instance.

For more information, see chapter 3 of http://aka.ms/zumobook

Comment: Cant I have a server residing logic to calculate something. I need to follow the thick server - thin client concept here. Isnt it possible with TableControllers?

Comment: Sure you can - check out http://aka.ms/zumobook - chapter 3 - for details.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
// Server method:
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAllProductItems")]
public IQueryable<ProductItem> GetAllProductItems()
{
    return Query();
}

// Client call
var result = await MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<IQueryable<ProductItem>>("ProductItem/GetAllProductItems", HttpMethod.Get, null);
```

Remember to add these attribute before the ProductItemController:

```
[MobileAppController]
[RoutePrefix("api/ProductItem")]
```

You can do the same thing to your `GetAllProductByMerchat(string merchantId)` method.

Comment: Hi, my question is for TableControllers. But your methodology seems for API controllers. Isn't it. Please correct me if Iam wrong

Comment: Use API Controllers if you want to call those server methods from client by their names.